# Restkit has suddenly stopped compiling today

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I am using RestKit in my project since a long time, using CocoaPods.

```
Podfile:pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.26.0'
```

Today, for unknown reasons, my project doesn't compile anymore. To the best of my knowledge, i have not changed any project settings or anything.

I get the error in RKObjectManager.h:

```
/projects/iphone/Pods/Headers/Public/RestKit/Network/RKObjectManager.h:892:49: 
Unknown type name 'AFNetworkReachabilityStatus'; did you mean 'SCNetworkReachabilityFlags'?
```

If i go into the h.file and click on the ReachabilityStatusEnum, i can see it, so it seems to be there although it says 'Unknown Type'.

I am at a loss as to how fix this. I followed the RestKit cocoapods instructions when i set it up a long time ago. Could it be because i upgraded xcode recently?

Very thankful for pointers...

Comment: Probably related to this issue: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/985

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that one, i spent some time looking ofc. The ticket is from 2012 and is marked as closed. Since it has worked for me up until today, i figured it must be something else...

Comment: Do you list AFNetworking in your Podfile, too? If so, this may cause the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, but that should not be needed, since RestKit has the dependency. I've never had it, and it worked yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so in the end, i had to add this to the .pch file. I have never had it there, and my project has built for over a year without it. Would be great to know why i suddenly had to include it...

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#else
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Do you known how can we add this in Swift Project.

Comment: @mathias any update? I would also love to get this working in a Swift project (cocoapods 1.0.1)

Comment: Sorry mate, i have no idea how to sort it out. I'm barely scraping by as it is :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with RestKit and cocoapods 1.0.1 (maybe also 1.0). What I did was install version 0.39 which I had used before.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
```

and then use this Version to install

```
pod _0.39.0_ install
```

solved the problem for me at least for the time being.

Comment: I confirm that RestKit does have build problems with cocoapods 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. You should use pre 1.0 versions of CocoaPods. If you have already the newer version installed `pod --version` do the following steps:

1. Install 0.39.0 version of CocoaPods `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0`
2. Setup it with `pod _0.39.0_ setup`
3. Check whether it worked well with `pod _0.39.0_ --version`

You should see 0.39.0.

**NOTE:** in certain cases you will see that the version of `pod _0.39.0_ --version` is still the same newer version that you are trying to override. In this case you have to use - `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`, then from the menu you will see in Terminal uninstall the newer version and finally get `pod _0.39.0_ --version` returning you exactly `0.39.0`.

Now you can run `pod install` as usual.

Do not forget to switch back to the actual version later :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me today.

**SOLVED**: Just change your Podfile from 0.26.0 to this:

> Podfile:pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.27.0'

and then, on terminal, run:

```
{your_machine}$  pod install
```

Now working for me :D