# Unknown type name 'AFNetworkReachabilityStatus', RestKit suddenly stop working

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, restkit

My application stops compiling today, and it has been working for a couple of month with RestKit. I did not change any code. What I did is only run the `pod install` command again.

I have tried the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271703/restkit-has-suddenly-stopped-compiling-today). This [issue](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/985) is already 3 years ago. I am using Swift, so I do not have the `.pch` file.

What I did is manually create the `Prefix.pch` file insert the code. It does not work for me. I also added the import into the `Briding-Header` file, also does not work.

Does anyone have the same problem with me?

Error message:

[image]

`Xcode: 7.2.1
RestKit: 0.25.0
AFNetworking: 1.3.4`

Comment: I also just started seeing this issue today. I didn’t update my project that uses RestKit, however I did update Cocoapods to the latest version (v1.0.0.beta.3), and suspect this might be part of the problem. I’ve yet to identify exactly _why_ it’s not working though.

Comment: @Stuart. OK, I also update cocoapods to v1.0.0.beta.3. I will try to downgrade to 0.39.0 and see if it still exits. I will let you known if it works.

Comment: After downgrade cocoapods to v0.39.0, RestKit can compile again.

Comment: OK, Finally. It is really no solution now. After downgrade to 0.39.0, the [pop](https://github.com/facebook/pop) pod does not compile. It shows me `include of non-modular header inside framework module pop.POP`

Comment: are you using use_frameworks! in your Podfile? Also, how are you importing the frameworks?

Comment: @CatalinaT.  Yes, i am using the use_frameworks!.   In bridging-header file, I put `#import <RestKit/CoreData.h> #import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`. `pop` is a dependency of my custom framework. I put `pod MyCustomFramework`

Comment: I got the same problem when I tried to use Restkit 0.24 version . But  I could solve this problem by using Cocoapods 1.0.0 & RestKit 0.26.0 version .. 
hope this will helpful for some one ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `use_frameworks!` you need to import your modules using `@import`. I think you need the import for both your custom framework and the `RestKit`.

Maybe you can also check my answer here about how to set up the bridging-header [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530532/4112491)

If it still does not work, please put the code that you are using to import the modules and I will try to help you forward. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have done, I created a new project, use `pod init` to create the Podfile, and `use_frameworks!`, and put `pod RestKit` under the target. When I compile it, it shows me that error already, It does not give me the chance to input code. It will have this error only with cocoapods 1.0.0. The 0.39.0 version can compile

Cocoapods: 1.0.0.beta.4