# Cannot find module FBSDKCoreKit Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate facebook into my app using CocoaPods, using the use_frameworks! tag, and according to facebook's [instructions here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced), also included the pod bolts.  When I try use `import FBSDKCoreKit` in my appdelegate, I get a no such module 'FBSDKCoreKit error.  I've included my podfile below:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.2'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

Additionally, in my Pods folder, there is a question mark next to Bolts, FBSDKCoreKit, and FBSDKSharekit, but not one next to alamofire, which I had been using previously.  In the Frameworks folder in my Pods project, FBSDKCoreKit and Bolts are listed there, but are both red.
Any ideas?  I've tried cleaning my project, and reinstalling and updating the pods.

Comment: how are you importing the FB modules?

Comment: @CatalinaT, I'm just using `import FBSDKCoreKit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by

1. Removing the Bridging Header.  Facebook SDK doesn't need them anymore after version 4.1
2. Adding all of the .frameworks to the Projects Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
3. Selecting each framework and building it.  You can do this by selecting your project name next to the run arrow.
4. Cleaning the project and restarting my computer.

Comment: Didn't you use cocoapods? Did you just copy .frameworks ?

Answer (score 2):

For people moving from `Carthage` to `Cocoapods` make sure to remove the Carthage references of the `FBSDKCoreKit` from the `Link Binary With Libraries` under `Build Phases` option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try below steps,

- Explicitly mention the versions i.e.

> pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~>5.8.0'
>
> pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~>5.8.0'
>
> pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~>5.8.0'

- Update pod repo using `sudo pod repo update`
- Update pod using `pod update`

Comment: That is a good solution because 5.8.0 doesn't require swift, 7.1.1 requires it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the facebook pods are Objective-C and they need a special way of importing in a swift project.

This is how I got it to work:

Create a bridging header in your project, if you dont have one(I created a new header file called `Bridging-Header.h` and set it as a bridging header in the project settings, like in the screenshot)
[image]

Then in this file import the facebook modules. Here's how my file looks like:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

@import FBSDKCoreKit;
@import FBSDKLoginKit;

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

Let me know if this workout for you or you need more help.

Comment: Is that for using CocoaPods? I didn't think that was needed with use_frameworks!.  Anyway, I did that but now get the message "Module 'FBSDKCoreKit' not found in the bridging-header file and a similar one for FBSDKLoginKit.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution, if you are using `Apple Swift Packages`:

1. Go to Navigator pane and select the project
2. Then make sure you choose project name under "**Project**" not under "**Targets**"
3. Then select **Package Dependencies** tab
4. You will find the Facebook package there, double click on it
   [image]
5. Change version to 9.0.0 and click "**Done**"
6. Rebuild, and it should be corrected.

Note that you may need [this url](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) to add Facebook SDK as `Apple Swift Packages` rather than Cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit/Swift'

Answer (score -2):

first add in pod file

```
 pod 'FacebookCore'
 pod 'FacebookLogin'
 pod 'FacebookShare'
```

this is facebook swift library,after that before using FBSDKCoreKit,just use FacebookCore then import FBSDKCoreKit

Comment: I had same error after installing these pods additionally