# Facebook for Unity SDK (iOS) - FBSDKCoreKit-Swift.h not found

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, unity-game-engine

We're developing a game with Unity 2019.4.28f1 (XCode 12.4).
I've upgraded Facebook to the latest sdk (11.0.0).
Trying to build iOS, XCode gives me a strange error:

"Swift Compiler error -- Header 'FBSDKCoreKit-Swift.h' not found

Here's a screen.

[image]

Have you ever seen this before?
I have tried to search about it but this module is not mentioned anywhere.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you make `pod update` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module FBSDKCoreKit Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527672/cannot-find-module-fbsdkcorekit-cocoapods)

Comment: @zeytin: Ops, I forgot to write it above: yes, I did. In the screenshot you can also see the content of the the Podfile.

Comment: @ElTomato: I tried to follow the thread but it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

search in `FBSDKLoginKit.framework`, can you find the header file `FBSDKLoginKit-Swift.h`?

Comment: No, -Swift is not present in FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKLoginKit frameworks.

Comment: What I mean is that you need to compile FBSDKLoginKit.framework first. After the compilation is completed, there will be a file FBSDKLoginKit-Swift.h in FBSDKLoginKit.framework. If there is no need to check the compilation problem